# How to convert jQuery live() to jQuery on() function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I just used jquery .live() function in jQuery v.1.7 for an asp.net webform app popup. The target is to load another .aspx page on click event using jquery popup dialog. Since new JQuery library doesn't support .live() anymore. I am unable to change it to .on() in the following code base.

## Html Part in aspx page:

```html
<div class="box-body">  
    <div id="MyLetters" class="block-body collapse in" >
         <asp:Repeater ID="LetterGrid" runat="server">
           <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Receive Date</th>
                      <th style="text-align:center">Sender Name</th>
                      <th style="text-align:center">Received By</th>
                      <th style="text-align:center">Delivery Date</th>
                      <th style="text-align:center">Receive Status</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <tr>
                  <td><span class="popup1" style="color:red"> <%# string.Format(" {0:dd/MM/yyyy}",Eval("ReceiveDate"))%></span></td>
                  <td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center"><%# Eval("SenderName")%></td>
                  <td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center"><%# Eval("ReceivedByName")%> </td>
                  <td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center"><%# Eval("DeliveryDate")%></td>
                  <td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center">
                      <label class="<%# Eval("ReceiveStatusClass")%>" aria-label="Left Align">
                          <%# Eval("ReceiveStatusName")%>
                        </label>
                  </td>    
                </tr>
           </ItemTemplate>                      
           <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody>
               </table>
           </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Javascript section:

```
$('a#popup1').live('click', function (e) {

    var page = $(this).attr("href");
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 350,
        width: 320, /* 'auto' */
        title: "Add To Do Items",
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $dialog.dialog('close');
                parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
        }
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I tried the following but no popup is displayed

```
$('.box-body').on('click', '#popup', function (e) {

    var page = $(this).attr("href");
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 480,
        width: 320, /* 'auto' */
        title: "Add Appointment Details",
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $dialog.dialog('close');
                parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
        }
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But the modal is not working. It is redirecting to that page.. no popup dialogue displayed.

Comment: `$('a#popup1')` also should not be working as you don't have any element that is `<a id="popup1"`.   So `.on("..", "#popup1",..` doesn't match any elements as there aren't any with id=popup1.   Code will work fine if your selectors are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @freedomn-m, `#popup1` is id selector but the `<a>` doesn't have id `popup1`.

In this code the `<a>` have class `popup1`, so it's better to use class selector `.popup1`.

```js
$('.box-body').on('click', '.popup1', function (e) {});
```

Comment: *#popup1 is id selector* - is not a problem in itself, the problem is that the `<a>` in question doesn't have `id=popup1`.   Better to change to class as in code above, but the *reason* is not that it's an "id selector".  OP could also change `<a class='popup1'>` to ``<a class='popup1' id="popup1">`